# Find the perfect numbers of the product of two primes, $2^p-1$ and $2^{p-1}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, mersenne-numbers

A number $n\in N$ Show that if $p$ is a prime, such that $2^p - 1$ is also a prime, a Mersenne prime that is, then $n = 2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ is a perfect number.

So I know that $n$ must be divisible by, $2^p-1$, $2^{p-1}$ and $1$ (the proper divisors of $n$), which sum up to be $2^p-1 + 2^{p-1} + 1 = 2^p + 2^{p-1}$. I'm stumped on where to go from here, since the sum isn't equal to $n$.

Comment: The sum of the divisors will be $(1 + (2^p - 1))(1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^{p-1})$, which actually does simplify to $2n$. How did you arrive at your answer?

Comment: The sum of the divisors of n are $2^{p-1}$ + $2^p-1$ + 1 = $2^p$ + $2^{p-1}$

Comment: Every number $2^k(2^p -1)^j$ for $0 \le k \le p-1$ and $0 \le j \le 1$ will be a divisor of $n$. You seem to have missed some of them?

Comment: Ahmad's answer expresses this more precisely using the [multiplicative $\sigma$ function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) You can see that since $2^p - 1$ and $2^{p-1}$ are coprime, the answer will be the sum of $2^{p-1}$'s divisors, times the sum of $2^p - 1$'s divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $2^p-1$ is prime number then $2^{p-1} (2^p -1)$ is perfect number if

$\sigma(2^{p-1} (2^p -1)) = \sigma(2^{p-1}) \sigma(2^p-1) = 2^p \sigma(2^{p-1}) = 2^p (2^{p}-1) = 2 * 2^{p-1} (2^{p}-1) $ twice the number we start with so its **perfect number**.

Done.